# DialogFragment not found in fragmentTransaction

Tags: android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmenttransaction, fragment-backstack

> I am displaying **DialogFragment** from a manager. DialogFragment display multiple times.

I want to know is there a way to check from transaction whether this fragment already displaying. So don't display it.

```
@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment prev = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (prev == null) {
            ft.add(this, tag);
            ///ft.addToBackStack(tag);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d("ABSDIALOGFRAG", "Exception", e);
    }
}
```

I am calling my Fragment like

```
CustomerFeedbackDialog feedbackDialog = CustomerFeedbackDialog.newInstance(genaric.getData(), type);

feedbackDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "feedbackDialog");
```

I have call findFragmentByTag  but it is always null. I don't want to show already displayed Fragment. otherwise it duplicate . Mulitple dialogFragment opens

I know I can do it using a flag in sharedprefs

**EDIT Solution found**

> Thanks for your help. Problem solved and I posted answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally able to handle it by overriding show method 
 and `addToBackStack(null)` and `executePendingTransactions`

> Firstly to put tag in **findFragmentByTag** `addToBackStack` is must otherwise tag is not added in fragmentTransaction.

```
    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        try {
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

            Fragment prev = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (prev == null) {
                ft.add(this, tag);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                manager.executePendingTransactions();
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("ABSDIALOGFRAG", "Exception", e);
        }
    }
```

Now if fragment is already in transaction. It will not display again..

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the same DialogFragment over another you can try adding a variable to your Manager:

```
@Nullable
private DialogFragment mCurrentDialogFrag;
```

And then whenever you add a new DialogFragment you set mCurrentDialogFrag to the new DialogFragment and then check before adding if current DialogFragment is the same as the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If I look into `DialogFragment`'s `public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)` method implementation, I can see this:

```
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        this.mDismissed = false;
        this.mShownByMe = true;
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

In order to know my dialog is already part of FragmentManager transactions, I'm simply doing this:

```
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("...the tag") == null) {
            fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "...the tag");
        }
```

I have to mention the above is strictly appcompat experience, and it works. Obviously you can put this check code inside override of `show` as well.